# A confusion on a continuous probability problem

Tags: probability, density-function

We are given a continuous Joint pdf
$$f(x,y)=\frac23(x+1), 0<x<1,0<y<1$$
We are to find $\textsf{P}(X<2Y<3X)$

What I did :
It is easy to see that the pdf's are independent and $f_X(x)=\frac23(x+1)$ and $f_Y(y)=1$ over the given support. Now, my probability is :
\begin{align*}
\textsf{P}(X<2Y<3X)&=\int_0^1f_{Y|X}(y)f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^1\int_{x/2}^{3x/2}1\cdot \frac23(x+1)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^1\frac23(x+1)\left(\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac23\int_0^1(x^2+x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac23\left(\frac13+\frac12\right)\\
&=\frac59\\
\end{align*}
What I want to know is that, am I correct? If not then what is the right proof? Thanks a lot.

Comment: (1) The double integral is mixed up: it looks like the inner integral is taken to be over $y$ rather than the outer integral as shown. (2) You went astray by forgetting that $y$ cannot exceed $1$, while the upper limit of $3x/2$ will exceed $1$ whenever $2/3\lt x\lt 1$. This causes your answer to be too large. (3) There is no need to invoke a conditional probability density: you have the full joint density at the outset.

Comment: Could you had the homework tag, please?

Comment: If you would only bother to _draw a diagram_ of the unit square with lines $y = x/2$ and $y=3x/2$, you will see that the region over which you have to integrate the joint pdf is a quadrilateral, and maybe it will induce you to think a bit as to how the integral might be broken up into a sum of integrals....

Comment: Oh I see it now, not that easy as I thought. Thanks for pointing that out.